# byte, word and double-word number representation

Tags: integer, x86-64, data-representation

I read a book which called `assembly64` and can be found [here](http://www.egr.unlv.edu/%7Eed/assembly64.pdf#page=35), now it says that - *A byte (8-bits) can be used to represent 256 different numbers, a word (16-bits) can be used to represent 65,536 different values, and a double-word (32-bits) can be used to represent 4,294,967,296 different numbers.  So, if you wanted to store a value of 100,000 then a double-word would be required.*

I don't under what does *represent x different values* mean? I know that a character is 1 byte and 256 is intended to be the ASCII table, but I didn't understand the following line - *a word (16-bits) can be used to represent 65,536 different values*, what's is the 65,536 values mean?

Comment: Simple example, assume you need to store the decimal number 7 in binary. The number 7 in binary is 111 ,  each 1 represents a bit,  ergo 3 bits. Each of the bits are 1, this means this is the biggest value what you can represent in with 3bits.
If you count from 0 to 7 in binary: 000, 001, 010, 011.... end up at 111. You will count 8 different values (000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111). 
This means on 3 bits you can represent 8 different values. 2^3=8

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand what "represent x different values" means.

If you have a data type that can store the values `0` and `1`, it can store two different values.

Thus, "represents x different values" means that, if you start from 0, it can store integers up to `x - 1`. That said, numbers are often signed, so the maximum is lower and the minimum is negative.

To find the maximum unsigned value given the number of bits, the calculation is `2^n - 1` if `n` is the number of bits.

On page 36 of the document you linked ([direct link](http://www.egr.unlv.edu/%7Eed/assembly64.pdf#page=36)), there's a table that details the possible values that can be stored in each data type, signed and unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

*The same thing goes to any of the datatypes you mention* - A byte is a group of 8 bits. A bit is the most basic unit and can be either 1 or 0. A byte is not just 8 values between 0 and 1, but 256 different combinations (rather permutations) ranging from 00000000 via e.g. 01010101 to 11111111 . Thus, one byte can represent a decimal number between 0(00) and 255.